# Role of stringsAsFactors in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Please look at this two dataframes in R.

When I run this code both emp.data1 and emp.data2 are the same despite stringsAsFactors in one of them is TRUE and in theother is FALSE.So what is the role of stringsAsFactors in dataframes?

```
# Create the data frame.
emp.data1 <- data.frame(
   emp_id = c (1:5), 
   emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary"),
   salary = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25), 

   start_date = as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2013-09-23", "2014-11-15", "2014-05-11",
      "2015-03-27")),
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE#Here stringsAsFactors is false
)
emp.data2 <- data.frame(
   emp_id = c (1:5), 
   emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary"),
   salary = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25), 

   start_date = as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2013-09-23", "2014-11-15", "2014-05-11",
      "2015-03-27")),
   stringsAsFactors = TRUE#Here stringsAsFactors is true
)
```

Comment: Compare `str(emp.data1)` and `str(emp.data2)`.

Comment: They are not *the same*, as you claim. Try `identical(emp.data1, emp.data2)` and `all.equal(emp.data1, emp.data2)`.

Answer (score 0):

[Read the docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/data.frame)

stringsAsFactors usually converts all strings that appear in the df to a factor variable instead of leaving at as a character variable. In statistical analysis, factors are useful for categorical variables. What you want to have depends on what you want to do with the data.

Comment: Additional information for people searching about stringsAsFactors. Since R ver 4.0 release, stringsAsFactors is set FALSE by default. The [R blog article](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/02/16/stringsasfactors/index.html) talks about the historical detail. Also, see [manual of data.frame](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.frame.html).

Answer (score 0):

This setting changes the data type of strings.

```
sapply(emp.data1, class)
  emp_id    emp_name      salary  start_date 
"integer" "character"   "numeric"      "Date" 

sapply(emp.data2, class)
  emp_id   emp_name     salary start_date 
"integer"   "factor"  "numeric"     "Date"
```

As you can see, the class of `emp_name` is `factor` when this option is turned off.

Factors are used when doing data analysis or visualization. For example, in the `iris` data set, that comes natively with R we can look at the distribution of petal length, and petal width, while using color to indicate the species.

```
require(ggplot2)
sapply(iris,class)
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width, color=Species)) +
    geom_point()
```

Labeling these as a factor let's R know that a sort of grouping is going on, and R will automatically determine the different groupings (or "levels") that are going on.

Explicit factor labeling allows you to optimally interact with data.